# Why would my code suddenly start throwing UnboundLocalError: local variable referenced before assignment errors?

Tags: python, python-2.7

My code below has suddenly started throwing a `UnboundLocalError:` on every variable.

Why would it suddenly be doing this?

Do I need to define `allowed_domains` outside of my `try:` and if so why wasn't the causing errors before?

Thanks.

```
File "/spiders/functions.py", line 85, in getAllowedDomains

return (allowed_domains)

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'allowed_domains' referenced before assignment
```

Code:

```
def getAllowedDomains():
    try:
        connection = lite.connect('links.db')
        c = connection.cursor()
        c.execute("SELECT site from sites")

        all_rows = c.fetchall()

        allowed_domains = []
        for row in all_rows:

            url = row[0]

            url = url[7:]
            print 'allowed url: '
            print url


            allowed_domains.append(url)

    except lite.Error, e:
        print "Error %s:" % e.args[0]

    finally:
        if connection:
            connection.close()


    return (allowed_domains)
```

Comment: create `allowed_domains = []` before `try:`. If you have error in code before `allowed_domains = []` then it doesn't create this variable and `return allowed_domains` gives you error message

Comment: @furas, neat that is what I have been doing. But now I am curious why this code worked up until recently?

Comment: remove `try/except` (for awhile) to see full error message which help you find problem.

Comment: Is it also printing the error message in `except lite.Error, e:` and does that message give you a hint? You are getting an error in the database connection or the select call, then you print a message but otherwise ignore the error. So, what do you want your function to do when there is a problem with the database call? If you want it to return an empty list, then you can define `allowed_domains` at the top of the function or just put a `return []` in the exception handler.